# How bind text in Taxonomy web tagging control with multi term sets

Tags: taxonomy, term-store, term

I have TaxonomyWebTaggingControl in my SharePoint 2010 application with three term sets:

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl ID="myWebTaggingControl"
AllowFillIn="True" IsMulti="True" IsDisplayPickerButton="False"
ContainerId="mycontenerID" runat="server">
</Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl>
```

In code behind I bind data to control:

```
var sspIds = new List<Guid> {TermStore.Id, TermStore.Id, TermStore.Id};
var termSetIds = new List<Guid> { TermSet1.Id, TermSet2.Id, TermSet3.Id};
myWebTaggingControl.SspId.AddRange(sspIds);
myWebTaggingControl.TermSetId.AddRange(termSetIds);
myWebTaggingControl.Text = text;
```

where text is term (label|guid;)

When I open the page, the text in control is ';' (should display label of term).
This is works correctly when I have one term set and one termstore:

```
var sspIds = new List<Guid> {TermStore.Id};
var termSetIds = new List<Guid> { TermSet1.Id};
```

How can I bind text to this control to work correctly with three term sets?

Answer (score 1):

Taxonomy web tagging control does not accept more than one term set. If you want to display data from three term set, add three tagging controls.

For more info check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.aspx

Comment: But SspId and TermSetId are a list of guids. This works correctly besides display the text.  Also autocomplete working correctly (I see terms from all three term sets). In my control I can add terms and saving is working, but when I want to display this, then it displays only semicolon.